# Kendo vue wrapper error on kendo-grid-column filterable props

Tags: kendo-ui-vue

I was trying to use the drop down filter on Kendo Grid. But i am getting the error,

`Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "filterable". Expected Boolean, got Object`.

```
<kendo-grid-column :filterable="{
        ui: statusFilter,
        operators: {
            string:{
                eq : 'Is equal to'
            }
        }
    }" field="status" title="Client Status" width="10%"></kendo-grid-column>
```

**Status Filter Method**

```
statusFilter(element) {
  this.$http.get("list/getclientstatus").then(({ data }) => {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: data,
      dataTextField: "text",
      dataValueField: "value",
      optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });
  });
```

I am using kendo `vue-templates` on grid for action method which is only available as the props.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/framework/vue-templates/

The version of kendo grid i am using : 2018.2.516,

So, i could not use this filter as:

```
columns: [
    {
      field: "status",
      title: "Client Status",
      filterable: {
        ui: this.statusFilter,
        operators: {
          string: {
            eq: "Is equal to"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This method is working very fine for me. But the filterable props as object is not working on my case.

What could be the workaround for this problem?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my kendo vue ui wrapper version, It is working as expected.

```
"@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper": "^2018.2.620",
```